# How do I use redis to cache HTTP Response objects

Tags: python, redis

I am trying to use redis as a caching backend for my HTTP responses. 
My problem is modelling the response object into redis.
In a document store, the data would look something like this:

```
def set_data(response):

  data= {

   '_id': key,

   'time': time(),

   'status': response.status,

   'url': response.url,

   'headers': dict(response.headers),

   'body': headers.body

   }
```

My problem lies in the field 'headers' as it is a dict.
In redis, can I nest the Hash data structure for my use-case?
What are some good design practices to model complex fields in redis? 
Should I store the headers with a different key? something like:

```
 headers_key= some_prefix+key
```

and then use the redis hash data structure to store the headers dict?
or should I just serialize my headers?

What should I be doing? I have looked into various ways i can do it, but I cant figure out which is the most optimal way. so I need some enlightenment on best practices that could be used for my use case in redis. Please Help.thank you.

Comment: The answers are in your question. No nested data structures in Redis. Serializing the headers is the simplest way around it. Using an additional hash is also possible if you are actually interested in the headers' discrete values and want to avoid serialization & deserialization.

Comment: but can i serialize the headers along with the rest of the data fields and be able to get the headers as a dict?  or should i have the headers in a separate entry?

Comment: Yes, you can choose between these two approaches. If you serialize the dict (e.g. with pickle or to JSON), you'll store it as a string in the hash. You'll be able to fetch it (hget) and deserialize the string back to a dict. Alternatively, you can decompose the dict into an independent hash. The first approach is CPU-"intensive " because every to the headers will require serialization. The independent hash approach is perhaps more costly in terms of RAM (depending on the serialization you choose to compare against), but allows easy access to each header item for reads or writes.

Comment: Thank you very much. thats exactly what I was trying to decide between. so that clears up things for me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` to serialize and de-serialize the dict. String object is good for redis to store.
Like:

```
import json
headers = json.dumps(dict(response.headers))
# then store it to redis
headers_dict = json.loads(headers)
# then it's a dict again
```